# What is a Chiral Algebra for a group?

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-representations, representation-theory, chirality

What do we mean by the Chiral Algebra for a group G (SO(3) etc )?

Do you know a reference suitable for physicists?

Thank you

Comment: The [nLab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chiral+Algebras) has links to the work of Beilinson and Drinfeld, who made the initially rather vague concept precise.